# What are the best tv shows for a 3 year old

Tags: toddler, television

I know, I'm a terrible dad but sometimes I have to plop the kid in front of the TV.  Are some shows better than others in terms of positive role models for girls, lack of violence, and learning?  She currently loves Kipper, wiggles, blues clues, and dora.

Comment: Impossible to answer what is 'best'. In general, TV isn't great for 3 year olds, but it sounds like you're plopping her in front of Nickelodeon and PBS Kids, and that seems as good as any.

Comment: Rather than asking for specific TV shows, this question would be better phrased along the lines of _"what factors make tv shows suitable for 3-year-olds?"_ Could you rephrase your question this way?

Answer (score 4):

Did you already check out the other questions tagged with [television](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/television)? Notable examples are (in no particular order):

- [How do you gauge if a show, movie or story may be too frightening for your child?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-do-you-gauge-if-a-show-movie-or-story-may-be-too-frightening-for-your-child)
- [Is there any consensus among researchers concerning the effects of watching television and the likes for a child's development?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/is-there-any-consensus-among-researchers-concerning-the-effects-of-watching-tele)
- [What TV shows are wholesome for primary-schoolers?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2273/what-tv-shows-are-wholesome-for-primary-schoolers)
- [How many hours of television per day are acceptable for a pre-schooler?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/982/how-many-hours-of-television-per-day-are-acceptable-for-a-pre-schooler)
- [At what age should a child be introduced to the Television?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3/at-what-age-should-a-child-be-introduced-to-the-television)

Generally speaking, toddlers should not watch a lot of TV, and not in long blocks of time,  and certainly not too much action (bad: Tom&Jerry -- better: Barbapapa, Bob the Builder). I would really recommend something that is **slow-paced,** something that can be enjoyed in **small chunks of time,** and **something you can stand hearing repeated** a hundred times over.

I would personally limit it to 15-minute sessions, maybe 2 or 3 times per day if you must, but I know I'm relatively conservative with these numbers. My toddler is happy with a single episode of *Barbapapa,* but the upbeat *Pink Panther* cartoons demand two or three episodes.

Comment: Thanks Torben. Forgive me, I'm new to stack exchange and my previous search appears to have been inadequate.

Comment: -1 @Torben, if you weren't a mod, I would flag this as not an answer. If there are already equivilent questions, shouldn't the question get marked as a duplicate (or as not constructive since he's essentially asking for a list)? And if there aren't equivilant questions, this doesn't answer the OP.

Comment: @smillig: don't let my being a mod stop you :-) I'm _also_ just a user! I promise I won't be offended. I don't think this question is a clear-cut duplicate because most existing questions aim at older children, not 3yo's. So I thought it'd be helpful to highlight the relevant among the existing ones, as well as provide my own answer.

Comment: damn. sorry for the controversy.  I'm getting the hang of this thing.  I promise.

Comment: Don't worry, @MarcMarasco :) Feel free to stop by our chat room if you want to discuss informally: [chat]

Answer (score 2):

I found Dora the Explorer was good, as it seemlessly introduced the concept of multiple languages. But you already have that one.

If you can pre-vet them, try nature programs too. Our girl (now 8) is a huge fan of David Attenborough.

Comment: I second nature programs, especially documentaries with no human but plenty of animals, it's fascinating for toddlers.  But I wanted to mention the [64 Zoo Lane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64_Zoo_Lane) series, which I (and our daughter) find of great value.  It's fun, slow-paced, the drawing is cool and easy to get, and subtly educational on how to behave.